# bash - return array from function and display contents

Tags: linux, bash

After some bash self study and experimenting, I am stuck with returning an array from a function, and for the life of me can't see my error.

In short, what this should/must do is by using a function
have a function which reads in values/strings from a file, returning an array:

- declare an array: clients
- assign the function's return array to array clients
- display array clients

It seems to me as if the function reads the whole file and not line by line, thus putting all strings into a single cell in the array, and I am not sure how to explicitly display clients[0] as this $(clients[0]) fails in bash code

If by an means I am doing something incorrectly, please point this out too or any suggestions on optimising this too

```
#!/bin/bash
readArray(){
        local array=()
        local i=0;
        local j=0
        while IFS= read -r LINE  && [[ -n "$LINE" ]] ; do 
                array[$((i++))]+=${LINE}; # Append line to the array
                ((j++))
        done < "$1";
        rtr=${array[@]}
}
string="/home/cybex/openvpntest/openvpn.log"
declare -a clients
#sed -i '/^$/d' $string
clients=$(readArray "$string")
echo "${clients[@]}"

echo -e "array not empty, displaying array contents\n"

for i in "${!clients[@]}"; do 
  echo "$i: ${clients[$i]}"
done
echo -e "\nfinished displaying contents of array"
```

cat openvpn.log

```
something
anotherthing
anotherlineoftext
here is one more line
and lastly
one with 
a few spaces
nice
```

**UPDATE**
For anyone wanting to see how I resolved this:

- declare a "global" array with

  ```
  declare -a clients
  ```
- while the function executes, add values DIRECTLY to the clients array

To display a single index position of an array, ref. last line of code

```
echo "${clients[0]}"      or any other number >=0
```

Working code:

```
declare -a clients
readArray(){
        local array=()
        local i=0;
        local j=0
        while IFS= read -r LINE  && [[ -n "$LINE" ]] ; do 
                clients[$((i++))]+=${LINE}; # Append line to the array
                ((j++))
        done < "$1";
}
string="/home/cybex/openvpntest/openvpn.log"
sed -i '/^$/d' $string
readArray "$string"
echo "${clients[@]}"

echo -e "array not empty, displaying array contents\n"

for i in "${!clients[@]}"; do 
  echo "$i: ${clients[$i]}"
done
echo -e "\nfinished displaying contents of array"
echo "${clients[0]}"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582763/how-to-return-an-array-in-bash-without-using-globals).

You should do a minimal search in google, because this was the first link returned for "bash return array"

## Edit:

In bash, functions don't return values. They can return a status (the same as other programs).

So, if you want to *return* something, you should use global variables that are updated inside your function.

Comment: I have seen this amongst many others, but this does not make sense to me. What should I be looking for? a return, a declare, what sends the array back?

Comment: update: ok that makes sense, I haven;t come across a post mentioning this, thanks

Comment: @cybex I think I have an answer.

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge what would that answer be?

Comment: @Cybex see my answer below. ;-)

Comment: FYI: this question was the first result from google for "bash formula return array" when I searched. Therefore, the leading paragraph hasn't aged well.

Answer (score 1):

### Discussion

If you have come to the point of wanting to return an array from a function, then you are probably aware that you can only return status codes. Boo! You say. :-)

What can we do with other data in a function that we want to use in another function / context?

1. **echo**

Assuming stdout is set to the terminal, at least you can see the contents of a variable or something.

2. **Output Redirection**: **>** or **>>**

Not ideal, but possible. :-) There are probably more things you can do, but let's stop here.

### Discussion continued ...

Let us say we think option #1 above sounds promising. What usually happens? Something like this ...

```
function listToString ()
{
    echo "$*"
}
```

Reference: *Your UNIX: The Ultimate Guide, 2nd Edition, p. 387 (last para)*.

If I call `doSomething`, it might, say, send a string message to stdout. That output can be captured in two different ways.

1. **Backticks** `doSomething`
2. **This thing:** $(doSomthing)

If that is true, then you can save something you send to stdout in another context.

```
var1=`doSomething`
```

or

```
var1=$(doSomething)
```

### In summary ....

Convert a list to a string. Echo the string. Capture the echoed string with command substitution (see above). Use `read` combined with a *here string* (`<<<`) to convert the string into an array. Use array at your leisure.

File: new_users

```
fsmith
jdoe
```

Let's say we wanted to add new users with a function we made called `addAccounts` that loops over username arguments. The order of march would be.

1. Make file
2. Read file
3. Convert list to a string
4. Convert the string to an array.

The code would be something like this

```
function listToString ()
{
    echo "$*"
}

usersString=$(listToString $(cat new_users))

read -a users <<< $usersString

addAccounts "${users[@]}"
```

`listToString` may not work with all lines of input. Test it on your input.

The last line should resolve to:

```
addAccounts "fsmith" "jdoe"
```

Many people will not understand the line ...

```
read -a users <<< $usersString
```

... because they have never heard of a here string.

This solution does not pass an array from a function, but it does allow you to convert the output of a function to an array. Some are satisfied with converting a list to a string and calling it a day, but if you truly want to deal with an official bash array, the here sting above will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This trick won't always work (When you have values with whitespaces, or you want to return values that depend on input values), but it usually does the work:

```
array_returning_func() {
    echo "cat dog tree"
}

declare -a arr="$(array_returning_func)"
for obj in ${arr[@]}; do
    echo "$obj"
done
```